# Is there a document that specifies un-installation of SQL server 2016 R server

Tags: sql-server, installation, r

Basically I want to remove all components of R server from SQL Server 2016 install?

Answer (score -1):

Try this guide, maybe it will work for you: [Cleanly Uninstalling Stubborn SQL Server Components](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/) by Aaron Bertrand.

The easiest way: Control Panel -> Programs & Features -> and uninstall every program that contains the words "SQL Server".

or, using PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | 
select @{Name='Guid';Expression={$_.PSChildName}}, @{Name='Disp';Expression={($_.GetValue("DisplayName"))}} | 
where-object {$_.Disp -ilike "*SQL*R"} | 
where-object {$_.Guid -like '{*'} | 
% {"rem " + $_.Disp; 'msiexec /x "' + $_.Guid + '"'; ''} > uninstallR2.bat
```